# Computing md5 hash

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

I am computing md5hash of files to check if identical so I wrote the following

```
private static byte[] GetMD5(string p)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Open);
    HashAlgorithm alg = new HMACMD5();
    byte[] hashValue = alg.ComputeHash(fs);
    fs.Close();
    return hashValue;
}
```

and to test if for the beginning I called it like

```
    var v1 = GetMD5("C:\\test.mp4");
    var v2 = GetMD5("C:\\test.mp4");
```

and from debugger I listed v1 and v2 values and they are different !! why is that ?

Comment: are the refenerences different or are there really different bytes in there?

Comment: @CarstenKönig they are different in bytes value ..the 16 bytes are diff

Comment: We need more code to determine the reason.

Comment: What leads you to believe they are different? Can you show us some output or a screenshot from the debugger?

Comment: Thanks...apparently i am using the wrong hashing algo I tried Darkshadw link which said MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
and it worked ..thanks for everyone who pressed "down" to my question , i will remove it ..

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're using `HMACMD5`, a keyed hashing algorithm, which combines a key with the input to produce a hash value.  When you create an HMACMD5 via it's default constructor, it will use a random key each time, therefore the hashes will always be different.

You need to use `MD5`:

```
private static byte[] GetMD5(string p)  
{  
  using(var fs = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Open))
  {
    using(var alg = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
      return alg.ComputeHash(fs);  
    }
  }
}
```

I've changed the code to use `using`s as well.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Security.Cryptography.MD5'

Comment: must be new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

Comment: @CnativeFreak yes, of course - doh - I always forget that class is `abstract`

Answer (score 5):

From the [HMACMD5 constructor doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sasyw6x0.aspx):

> HMACMD5 is a type of keyed hash algorithm that is constructed from the
>   MD5 hash function and used as a Hash-based Message Authentication Code
>   (HMAC). The HMAC process mixes a secret key with the message data,
>   hashes the result with the hash function, mixes that hash value with
>   the secret key again, and then applies the hash function a second
>   time. The output hash will be 128 bits in length.
>
> With this constructor, a 64-byte, *randomly generated* key is used.

(Emphasis mine)

With every call to `GetMD5()`, you're generating a new random key.

You might want to use [`System.Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cng.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...apparently i am using the wrong hashing algo I tried Darkshadw link which said  
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider(); and it worked

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you did something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(v1);
Console.WriteLine(v2);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(v1 == v2);
```

That just shows that the variable values refer to distinct arrays - it doesn't say anything about the values *within* those arrays.

Instead, try this (to print out the hex):

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(v1));
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(v2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ToString()** methode to get the value of the array byte